# API Endpoints with R Plumber and Plotly Exception Error

Tags: r, rest, plumber

Suppose the contents of my plumber.r file are as follows below. I can successfully test each endpoint by visiting the path using chrome and viewing the expected output except for the \plotly endpoint.

When visiting that in my browser (i.e., http://localhost:8000/plotly) I get "An exception error occurred". I am not using R Studio, I am launching this from an RGui session using

```
pr("plumber.R") %>%  pr_run(port=8000)
```

Any advice on where my error is?

###plumber.R

```
library(plotly)
#* Plot a histogram
#* @serializer png
#* @get /plot
function() {
  rand <- rnorm(100)
  hist(rand)
}

#* Return the sum of two numbers
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @get /sum
function(a, b) {
  as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
}

#* Echo back the input
#* @get /dat
function() {
  data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), v2 = c(5,6,7,8))
}

#* @apiTitle HTML widgets API#* @apiTitle HTML widgets API
#* Return interactive plot using plotly
#* @serializer htmlwidget
#* @get /plotly
function() {
    fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
    fig
}
```

#### Editing to show how this is solved with Pandoc

I am doing this with Vanilla RGui 4.1.3 and not with the RStudio IDE. So, I manually installed Pandoc 2.17.1.1. Following the advice of @jpiversen below, I did the following.

I first manually use setwd() to the location where Pandoc is locally installed. I needed this because the `htmlwidgets:::find_pandoc()` does not have an argument for the path, it scans the directory. After setting the working directory, then run

```
htmlwidgets:::find_pandoc()
htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$version
htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$dir
```

This solved the issue and I can now view the plotly endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update based on comments

The error message:

```r
<simpleError in htmlwidgets::saveWidget(val, tmpfile, selfcontained = TRUE, ...): Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see: github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md>
```

seems to correspond to the function [`plumber::serializer_htmlwidget()`](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/54fc7f779ae864bbb9edc017a15c4e3bf2bae2a7/R/serializer-htmlwidget.R) where its calling `htmlwidget::saveWidget()`.

In the source code for [`htmlwidget::saveWidget()`](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/R/savewidget.R) we can see that the excact error message is triggered by `!pandoc_available()`.

`htmlwidget::pandoc_available()` differs from `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()`, and somehow it is not finding your pandoc. Try running:

```r
htmlwidgets:::find_pandoc()
htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$version
htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$dir
```

##### Original answer

This seems to be running fine - it's probably just that you cannot see it in Swagger.

If you run this from swagger, you get the HTML-code needed for the plot:

[image: Screenshot swagger]

But if you instead go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/plotly` in your browser, you should see the plotly widget:

[image: Screenshot browser]

> Sorry about the small image size.

Comment: this is a helpful confirmation, thank you. I'm still encountering an issue, but this is clearly user error. I get the following, even when testing the API in swagger (locally). Perhaps someone sees a dependency I am missing. I installed pandoc, but the linked suggested by the error is broken. ```<simpleError in htmlwidgets::saveWidget(val, tmpfile, selfcontained = TRUE, ...): Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md>'''

Comment: What do you get if you run `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()`?

Comment: I get same error. I'm using pandoc 2.17.1.1 with R 4.1.3  rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE

Comment: Hmm, strange. I have the same version of pandoc and R. I use version 1.1.0 for plumber and 1.5.4 for htmlwidgets, and it's working fine here.

Comment: If it's any help, I guess it's line 25 [here](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/54fc7f779ae864bbb9edc017a15c4e3bf2bae2a7/R/serializer-htmlwidget.R) that gives you trouble. Unsure why.

Comment: And the source code of `htmlwidget::saveWidget()` shows that the excact error message you get is triggered by `!pandoc_available()`, so somehow R cannot find your pandoc installation. 

Did you restart R after installing it?

Comment: I did. I started with ```rmarkdown::find_pandoc(dir='myPath\\Pandoc')``` and then use ```> rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE```
which is evaluating to TRUE.

Comment: I see that `htmlwidget` has a slightly different `find_pandoc()`. Do you get the same results if you run `htmlwidgets:::find_pandoc(); htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$version; htmlwidgets:::.pandoc$dir` ?

Comment: That does indeed solve the problem. But, it took a small amount of legwork on my end so editing my post above to show how I was able to get this to work

Comment: Strange problem - glad we found the solution. I updated my answer with a summary of our discussion in the comments. Please consider accepting the answer.